# Git Merging - How does it predict which piece of code are to be kept?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Suppose we are merging two branches, then how does git identifies which piece of code are to be omitted and which piece of code are to be kept.

I read the following thing somewhere

Let `A` represent a piece of code.
Suppose in `branch-1` this piece of code is deleted however in `branch-2` this piece of code is left untouched, then while merging these two branches `A` will be omitted.

I don't know exactly what author was trying to say, either author was trying to illustrate the concept of merging strategy or is it an actual merging strategy ?

Is this strategy used by git ? If used isn't it a bad strategy, since the omitted piece of code might be related to some other piece of code.

I am really sorry if question is silly, It would be great help if someone could answer.

Answer (score 0):

Git reasons in terms of patches: when you merge two branchs, the resulting commit will be the result of every patches from the two branches. (Note that if different modifications are applied to the same lines of code, it will likely result in a merge conflict which can only be solved by a human)

Hence, in your example, only one modification has been applied to `A`: it has been deleted. So the resulting merge will not contain `A`.

On the other hand, if `branch-1` deletes `A` and `branch-2` changes it, then Git will give up, and produce a merge conflict.

> the omitted piece of code might be related to some other piece of code.

Indeed, if `branch-1` removes an unused method `f`, but `branch-2` adds a method `g` which relies on `f`, then Git will believe it is able to merge them without conflict, but it will produce a corrupted code base.

Fortunately, it's easy to face it: you just need to run your non regression test suit before pushing your commits.